# Getting ObjectContext error even after calling ToList

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

When calling the method directly below I get a ObjectDisposedException when calling Mapper.Map with the retrieved list.

> System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

```
public IEnumerable<Models.Provider> Get(string owner)
{
    List<Data.Models.Provider> providers;

    using (var db = new Data.ProviderDirectoryContext())
    {
        providers = db.Providers.Where(p => p.Owner.Name == owner).ToList();
    }

    var dtoProviders = Mapper.Map<List<Data.Models.Provider>, List<Models.Provider>>(providers);
    return dtoProviders;
}
```

I previously had the code like this (below), I wasn't getting an error, but the database was getting pounded when doing the mapping, and it was taking too long.  I don't want to hit the database, when doing the mapping.

```
public IEnumerable<Models.Provider> Get(string owner)
{
    using (var db = new Data.ProviderDirectoryContext())
    {
        var providers = db.Providers.Where(p => p.Owner.Name == owner).ToList();
        var dtoProviders = Mapper.Map<List<Data.Models.Provider>, List<Models.Provider>>(providers);
        return dtoProviders;
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve all the data before doing the mapping?

Here is the DbContext and the Data.Models.Provider for your reference.

```
public class ProviderDirectoryContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LocationAuditLog> LocationAuditLog { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Office> Offices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OfficePhoneNumber> OfficePhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OfficeAuditLog> OfficeAuditLog { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OfficeDay> OfficeDays { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Provider> Providers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProviderPhoneNumber> ProviderPhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProviderAuditLog> ProviderAuditLog { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ProviderType> ProviderTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProviderSpecialty> ProviderSpecialties { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Provider>().HasRequired(cn => cn.Owner).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Office>().HasRequired(cn => cn.Owner).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public class Provider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }

    public int? ProviderTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProviderType ProviderType { get; set; }

    public int? ProviderSpecialtyId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProviderSpecialty ProviderSpecialty { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(75)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(75)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(75)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProviderPhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }

    public string Note { get; set; }

    public DateTime? InactiveOn { get; set; }

    public int OfficeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Office Office { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProviderAuditLog> AuditLog { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(75)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(75)]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: To you have any functions/properties inside `Data.Models.Provider` who access any context functions?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @StephenReindl. I don't think I'm doing anything special in `Data.Models.Provider`, but I've added it to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `Models.Provider` class contains other classes like `Models.Office`, and `Models.PhoneNumbers` that were not eagerly loaded by the query.  In addition to that, the `Models.Provider` class needs to be flattened. The Mapper wants to recursively map everything, and it keeps going down to the next class.  For example, `Provider.Office.Location.Offices`.

The solution is to flatten `Models.Provider` and add .Include() to the query so it eagerly loads the data required.

I'll clean this up a bit more, but this is currently working.

```
public IEnumerable<Models.Provider> Get(string owner)
{
    List<Data.Models.Provider> providers;
    using (var db = new Data.ProviderDirectoryContext())
    {
        providers = db.Providers
            .Where(p => p.Owner.Name == owner)
            .Include("ProviderType")
            .Include("ProviderSpecialty")
            .Include("Office")
            .Include("PhoneNumbers")
            .ToList();
    }
    var dtoProviders = Mapper.Map<List<Data.Models.Provider>, List<Models.Provider>>(providers);
    return dtoProviders;
    }

public class Provider
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    public int OfficeId { get; set; }
    public string OfficeName { get; set; }

    public int? ProviderTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ProviderTypeName { get; set; }

    public int? ProviderSpecialtyId { get; set; }
    public string ProviderSpecialtyName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }

    public string Note { get; set; }

    public DateTime? InactiveOn { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much this will help with performance but declaring the variable you don't want to dispose outside the using statement should fix your dispose exception.

```
   public IEnumerable<Models.Provider> Get(string owner)
     {

    IEnumerable<Models.Provider> dtoProviders;
    using (var db = new Data.ProviderDirectoryContext())
    {
        List<Data.Models.Provider> providers = db.Providers.Where(p => p.Owner.Name == owner).ToList();

        dtoProviders = Mapper.Map<List<Data.Models.Provider>, List<Models.Provider>>(providers);
    }


    return dtoProviders;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jackncoke.  While this does help with the exception, the performance is terrible.  There are about 6,000 providers and it takes 36+ seconds to do the mapping.

Comment: Do you need every property that you are mapping? Can you create a shorter version of that class with only what you need? That should decrease your mapping time.

Comment: Thanks @jackncode, but I found the problem.  I'll post the answer.